# Angular - Force select value to be integer

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <select name="area_id" formControlName="area_id">
        <option value="1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="3">Value 3</option>
    </select>
</form>

<pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>
```

If I select an option, the value will be string. How can I force the value to be integer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `ngValue` for values that are not strings

```ts
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <select name="area_id" formControlName="area_id">
        <option [ngValue]="1">Value 1</option>
        <option [ngValue]="2">Value 2</option>
        <option [ngValue]="3">Value 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I haven't tried this with model-driven forms myself yet, only with

```ts
<select [(ngModel)]="someField" name="area_id" formControlName="area_id">
```

but it might still work.

Answer (score 1):

**Code is attached below**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<select [(ngModel)]="selectedVal" (change)="handleSelectionChange()">
                    <option *ngFor="let item of list" [ngValue]="item.id" >
                        {{item.text}}
                    </option>
                </select>
              `
})

export class MainComponent {
    list: [] = [{
        id: 12,
        text: 'Suneet'
    }, {
        id: 13,
        text: 'Bansal'
    }];

    handleSelectionChange() {
        alert(this.selectedVal);
    }
}
```